# Not able to login Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04

Not able to login to my Ubuntu 14.04.  l tried chown username:username .Xauthority and other suggestions posted online like reinstalling lightdm and installing gdm but nothing seems to help. The file .xsession.errors says /etc/X11/Xsession.d/99x11-common_start: init: not found

Comment: What was your solution?